# Adicionar variável dentro do editor tinymce

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

Estou usando o https://www.tiny.cloud/ para criar um editor de texto.

No momento da edição, é necessário adicionar variáveis, que no momento da impressão serão trocados pelo valor correspondente a cada variável.

Exemplo: A variável $eCNPJ, será substituta e ira aparecer o CNPJ correspondente.

**PROBLEMA:**

Ao clicar na variável, ela deveria aparecer no dentro do editor na posição marcada, isso não está acontecendo.

CÓDIGO:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea'
  });


  $('.button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#editor1').tinymce('insertText', ` ${this.innerText} `);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor1" class="form-control" name="texto"></textarea>

<br>

<small><strong>ESCOLA...:</strong>
      <a href="#" title="CNPJ" class="button">$eCNPJ</a>
      - <a href="#" title="Rasão Social" class="button">$eRSocial</a>
      - <a href="#" title="Nome Fantasia" class="button"> $eNFantasia</a>
      - <a href="#" title="E-mail" class="button"> $eEmail</a>
      - <a href="#" title="Telefone" class="button"> $eTelefone</a>
    </small>
```

Comment: De onde vem o número do CNPJ, por exemplo?

Comment: Eu tenho um arquivo separado que faz a troca das variáveis somente quando vai gerar o PDF. Nessa tela vou apenas salvar no banco de dados.

Comment: Troque a linha que insere o texto por esta: `tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, ' '+ this.innerText +' ');`... veja se funciona na versão que vc está usando.

Comment: @Sam, funcionou. Coloca como resposta para eu marcar como resolvido. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de usar `.tinymce('insertText'...`, use o comando `mceInsertContent`:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, ` ${this.innerText} `);
```

Irá inserir um texto na posição onde estiver editando.

[**Veja documentação**](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/TinyMCE3x@Command_identifiers/)